# tweak is not work iphone6 (Jail Broken development)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I'm just started Tweak development and I got a problem. tested My Tweak on iPhone4 and iPhone6(both are iOS8.1.2). 
Developed using the THEOS.
After install Tweak(use "make install"), execute "uicache", "killall SpringBoard" and reboot device. The tweak is work on iPhone4 but it isn't work on iPhone6. Please tell me how do I do on iPhone6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to mark the architecture. in the makefile add :

ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64

Comment: `armv7s` is not strictly required though.